# Mutable parameters on swift closure using Objective-c typedef

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures

I have an objective c typedef I want to use with my swift closure:

```
    typedef void (^SBJson4ValueBlock)(id item, BOOL* stop);
```

My closure is fine, except for when I want to set "stop".

```
    let parseJsonBlock: SBJson4ValueBlock = {
        item, stop in

        let continueFlag = doStuff(item)
        stop = !continueFlag
    }
```

Stop is obviously mutable in the objective-c version, as it's passed by reference... but I get "cannot assign to value: 'stop' is a 'let' constant". How can I make swift understand this parameter should be mutable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can set `stop` using `memory` like so:

```
if !continueFlag { stop.memory = true }
```

Or, you can do:

```
stop.memory = ObjCBool(!continueFlag)
```

Comment: I had to use ... stop.memory = ObjCBool(!continueFlag). If you can update your answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Revised answer accordingly.